# Writing to xlsx creating duplicate lines in one cell

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm reading data from `in.txt` and writing specific lines from that to `Sample.xlsx`. I'm grepping data between lines containing `start` and `end` and I set `Flag` when I'm parsing this section of input data. When `Flag` is set, whenever I encounter `NAME:` and `AGE:` in lines, it needs to be written to C and D columns respectively (Extra info: input file has the following pattern: first line contains `NAME`, next line contains `AGE` followed by an empty line and this pattern is repeated).

```
start is here
NAME:Abe
AGE:40

NAME:John
AGE:20

...
end
```

Input is similar to above. Now the problem is that I've around 1000 such lines, so roughly 333 NAMES, AGE. When I open excel sheet after running the code, I see that C2 has `NAME:Abe` repeated 21 times. D2 has `AGE:40` repeated 21 times too. I reduced input to 100 lines, and the repetition reduced to 3. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. When I change to 10 lines, ie just 3 name and age, this problem doesn't happen. C2 just has one name, C3 also one name.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook  
fin = open('in.txt')
fout1 = open('name.txt','w')
fout2 = open('age.txt','w')

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

i = 2
Flag = False
for lines in fin:
    if 'start' in lines:
        Flag = True
        continue
    if Flag and 'end' in lines:
        break
    if Flag:
        if 'NAME:' in lines:
            fout1.write(lines)
            ws['C'+str(i)] = lines
        elif 'AGE:' in lines:
            fout2.write(lines)
            ws['D'+str(i)] = lines
            i += 1
wb.save(filename = 'Sample.xlsx')
```

Apologizing for the long write up. But please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks for reading.

______________________________________ Edit-1 ________________________________

I just tried basic writing from text file to excel cells using the following minimal code.

```
for line in fin:
    ws['C'+str(i)] = line
    i += 1
```

This also creates the same error. Line gets written multiple times inside a cell. And the number of times it's getting repeated increases based on the number of lines in input text file.

__________________________________ Edit-2__________________________________

I seem to have fixed the issue, but still don't know why it got fixed. Since strings were getting printed without any issue, I removed last character from `lines` which should be next-line character. And everything is working as expected now. I'm not sure if this is a proper solution or why this is even happening. Anyway the below given code seems to resolve this issue.

```
for line in fin:
    ws['C'+str(i)] = line[:-1]
    i += 1
```

Comment: I suspect there are problems with your counter. You should add some debugging code to see if it's behaving as you want.

Comment: I thought so too. But I changed `ws['C'+str(i)] = lines` to `ws['C'+str(i)] = 'hello'` and similarly for column D. And after doing so, `'hello'` appears only once in one cell. Problem happens when I'm assigning current `lines` to that cell. It just gets repeated multiple times.

Comment: Also I'm writing name and age to text files as well under the same conditional statements. And text file outputs doesn't have any repetitions.

Comment: Writing to the other files doesn't involve the counter. As I said, add some debugging code to see under which conditions something is being written.

Comment: Yea, text output doesn't involve counter. Still when I assign a string like `'hello'` instead of `lines` it doesn't repeat within a cell. I'll keep trying.

Comment: The newline character should not matter, but you can use `fin.readlines()` to strip these. The code runs on my machine without any problems so the problem is probably something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and advisable to try and avoid using a counter in Python. The following code is more expressive and maintainable.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
fin = open('in.txt', 'r')

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append([None, None, "NAME", "AGE"])

Flag = False
for line in fin.readlines():

    if line.startswith("start"):
        Flag = True
        row = [None, None, None, None]

    elif line.startswith("end"):
        break

    elif Flag:
        if line.startswith('NAME:'):
            row[2] = line[5:]

        elif line.startswith('AGE:'):
            row[3] = int(line[4:])
            ws.append(row)

wb.save(filename = 'Sample.xlsx')
fin.close()
```